# Is there an option to query enum description instead of value

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, vue-apollo

I query some type from graphql schema, and for a specific field, I want to get it with the enum description instead of the enum value.

```
type Gigi {
   a: SomeEnum!
   b: Int!
}

enum SomeEnum {
   "Bla"
   BLA

   "Foo"
   FOO
}
```

I want to get the 'Gigi.a' field, with the description of the enum.
For example:

```
{
   a: "Bla"
   b: 5
}
```

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Descriptions of types, fields and enum values exist for documentation purposes only and are therefore only accessibly through an introspection query:

```
query {
  __type(name: "SomeEnum") {
    enumValues {
      name
      description
    }
  }
}
```

Also note that there is nothing in the spec that requires enum values to be in all caps, so you can have an enum like:

```
enum SomeEnum {
  Bla
  Foo
}
```

Comment: thank's for the answer! I use the description on the client side. I will find another way to do it :)

Comment: @YairCohen You could always run the introspection query when you initialize your client and then apply the transformation client-side. Depending on your use case, you might also consider wrapping the enum in a type that would include both the enum value and the description. Or just return a String instead of the enum for the field and apply the transformation inside the field's resolver.

Comment: I think I will choose to set the enums on the server-side just with their values, and set enums that include both the values and the description on the client-side, and make the two-way transformation on the client. Thank's again for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Extending the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57445851/8130763

// **schema.graphql**

```
type Gigi {
    a: SomeEnum!
    b: Int!
    c: SecondEnum!
}

enum SomeEnum {
    "Bla"
    BLA

    "Foo"
    FOO

    "Description with spaces"
    DescriptionWithSpaceEnumValueInPascalCase
}

enum SecondEnum {
    "moo one"
    MooOne

    "moo two"
    MooTwo
}
```

// **query**

```
query {
    a
    SomeEnum: __type(name: "SomeEnum") {
        enumValues {
            description
            name
        }
    }
    SecondEnum: __type(name: "SecondEnum") {
        enumValues {
            description
            name
        }
    }
}
```

// **sample response**

```
{
    "data": {
        "a": "DescriptionWithSpaceEnumValueInPascalCase",
        "c": "MooOne"
    },
    "SomeEnum": {
        "enumValues": [
            {
                "description": "Bla",
                "name": "BLA"
            },
            {
                "description": "Foo",
                "name": "FOO"
            },
            {
                "description": "Description with spaces",
                "name": "DescriptionWithSpaceEnumValueInPascalCase"
            }
        ]
    },
    "SecondEnum": {
        "enumValues": [
            {
                "description": "moo one",
                "name": "MooOne"
            },
            {
                "description": "moo two",
                "name": "MooTwo"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```